# Writing file to S3 with AWS Lambda errors - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a pandas dataframe to S3 bucket in AWS Lambda, my code:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import s3fs
from io import StringIO

...

bucket = 'info' # already created on S3
csv_buffer = StringIO()
result.to_csv(csv_buffer)
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'testing.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

I have turned off the public access blocking. When I go to the bucket -> access points there is this: `Access points can be used to provide access to your bucket. The S3 console doesn't support using virtual private cloud (VPC) access points to access bucket resources. To access bucket resources from a VPC access point, you’ll need to use the AWS CLI, AWS SDK, or Amazon S3 REST API.`

Does that mean I can't write files to S3 with AWS lambda the way I am trying to?

Comment: Few important things missing: is your lambda in VPC? Do you use S3 VPC endpoint to access S3? Do you try to upload to bucket or bucket access point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to grant your lambda a permission allowing it to write to your S3 bucket. In the link below it is explained how to do it.

- [How do I allow my Lambda execution role to access my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/)